# Replacing String in log Using Sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have access log like:

```
10.2.21.120 - - [26/Jan/2013:19:15:11 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "Mozilla/0.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/000.00 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.0.0000.00 Safari/000.00"
```

I  want to replace the user-agent. Resulting:

```
10.2.21.120 - - [26/Jan/2013:19:15:11 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "NetScape"
```

I try to change all after `"-"` but Sed skips `""` and change all after `-`

something like this `sed 's/[(][^)]*[)]/\(NetScape\)/g'` input` change user-agent only in brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`,  you may replace the substring between quotes at the end of the line:

```
sed 's/"[^"]*"$/"NetScape"/'
```

Here, `"[^"]*"$` matches `"`, then 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"` at the end of the line. You do not need the `g` operator since `sed` processes files  line by line.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/2C5S67):

```
log='10.2.21.120 - - [26/Jan/2013:19:15:11 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "Mozilla/0.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/000.00 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.0.0000.00 Safari/000.00"'
sed 's/"[^"]*"$/"NetScape"/' <<< "$log"
# => 10.2.21.120 - - [26/Jan/2013:19:15:11 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "NetScape"
```